# Mapbox map dimensions with within Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, leaflet, mapbox

Context: Using Twitter Bootstrap and maps as the "slides" of the carousel

I´m trying to specify the dimensions of the map either using

`var map = mapbox.map('map',false, {x: 940, y: 500});`

or

```
#map { 
width: 940px;
height: 500 px
}
```

Both of them lead to this:
[image: streeeched]

which basically it´s a x-streched version that only displays ok with x=256 (one tile width, right?)

`var map = mapbox.map('map',false, {x: 256, y: 500});`

[image: cropped]

You can see the problem [here](http://smeadaptation.org/) (pass to the second page of the carousel, the first one uses the iframe).

I´m writing because I´ve already tried the [documentation](http://mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v0.6.7/#mapbox.map) via mapbox.map(dimensions) and via the CSS dimensions, and oddly seems to work for height but not for width.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems some CSS properties need to be overwritten from Bootstap.

Tom sent me a fix via [Mapbox support](http://support.mapbox.com/discussions/general-questions/14920-map-size).

```
#map1 img {
 max-width: none;
 min-width: 0px;
}
```

and also add `height: auto;` so that the markers work too.